# Outlook 2007 Contacts Tab Empty, but TO: field Populates Addresses

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, contacts, address-book

In Outlook 2007 when creating a new message I am able to type a letter or name in the "To:" field and have suggestions auto-complete. However, in the **CONTACTS tab** of Outlook 2007 there are no contacts listed at all. I am needing to **EXPORT** my contacts list (all the names and email addresses that show in the auto-complete "to:" field) to a new laptop and I'm switching to Thunderbird (Outlook 2013 is a mess to look at).

Where are these contacts stored that are auto-completed?

I have researched only to find answers of people having the reverse problem (contacts are in the CONTACTS tab but not showing up in the auto-complete).

I have also exported the .PST file and imported on another laptop with Outlook 2003, and no contacts are imported and the "to:" field does not have an auto-complete.

Comment: FYI: The To: field auto-fill and the Contacts are completely separate things that don't depend on each-other.  Relative to this, the To auto-fill entries are not exported with a PST file.

Comment: @techie007 - that is the nature of my question...to find out what the difference is and where to find it and utilize it. And I did not come across that similar post you linked to, but thank you for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AutoCorrect addresses are kept in *.N2K files, but according to the linked page, that changed in Outlook 2010. To make it easy on yourself, just download Nirsoft's N2K Edit and export your contacts from there to a format of your choice so that you can import it into Thunderbird.

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/outlook_nk2_edit.html

Comment: Yes! That is pure gold. Why is this information so hard to find on the internet. Thank you.